# Como debo hacer para que un boton me expulse del programa pero antes de eso reproduzca un sonido wav? (Jframe Java Netbeans)

Tags: java, netbeans, jframe

quiero que un boton se salga de mi programa en ejecucion, pero de igual forma quiero que al presionarlo primero me reproduzca un sonido (antes de botar el programa)...
¿Cómo he de lograrlo?

Comment: Tu necesitas una manera de reproducir sonidos o también como implementar botones en Swing?

Comment: @StefanNolde yo requiero implementar el sonido en el boton y despues que este mismo (al terminar el sonido) expulse el programa (cierre).  Te agradezco

Comment: Bueno, te lo agrego.

Answer (score 0):

Buenas

Primeramente disculpas, mi respuesta es de memoria y puede no ser tan exacta como me gustaría.

1: Depende de con que botón quieres que se cierre el programa, por ejemplo, puedes simplemente sobreescribir el comportamiento de la ventana principal para que al cerrarse termine la ejecución y, de paso, realice procedimientos que tu deseas. Un ejemplo típico suele ser definir esta lógica en el constructor del JFrame principal, tal que así:

```
public Aplicacion() {

    this.setResizable(false);
    // Definimos comportamiento en el cierre
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
            //bd.eliminarTablas();
            bd.cerrarDB();
        }
    });              

    initComponents(); // Inciamos el resto de componentes
}
```

Respecto al sonido, creo recordar que una vez puedes reproducirlo, tiene un "isRunning", "isPlaying" o similar. Podrías hacer algo similar a

```
while(sonido.isRunning)
{
 thread.sleep(1000);
}
```

Quedando, en el ejemplo que he puesto algo similar a (lo siento, aquí pongo algo de  pseudocódigo, pero no debería costarte traducirlo)

```
this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
this.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
        sonido.start();
        while (sonido.isRunning)
        {
          thread.sleep(1000); // No es necesario realmente, pero es más limpio que tener el bucle constantemente corriendo
        }
        sonido.close();
      // Cualquier otra cosa o metodo que quieras ejecutar antes del cierre
    }
});
```

Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Para tocar un sonido puedes usar `AudioSystem` creando un `Clip` desde un archivo *.wav*:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException;
import javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException;

/**
 * @author snolde
 *
 */
public class Audio implements Runnable, ActionListener{

    private long sleep;
    private File wav;



    public Audio(File wav, long sleep){
        this.wav = wav;
        this.sleep = sleep; // tiempo de espera
    }

    @Override
    actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        run();
        System.exit(0);            
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        AudioInputStream ais;
        try {
            ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(wav);
            try {
                Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
                clip.open(ais);
                try {
                    clip.start();
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(sleep);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    clip.drain();
                } finally {
                    clip.close();
                }
            } catch (LineUnavailableException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                ais.close();
            }
        } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Audio(new File("Bell.wav"),100L).run();
    }
}
```

El tiempo de espera se necesita para no cerrar el clip antes que toca. No se necesita la duración completa. Lo implementé como `Runnable, así alternativamente se puede usar para tocar sonidos en un`Thread`:

```
new Audio(new File("ejemplo.wav"),20L).start();
// seguir con código mientras el sonido suena
```

Implementando `ActionListener`, el sonido se puede agregar simplemente al `JButton`:

```
JButton button = new JButton("Cerrar");
button.addActionListener(new Audio(new File("exit.wav"), 20L));
```